# Can we make a region on global page not load every time in oracle apex(make it static). Is there a way to restrict it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, plsql, oracle-apex

I am using an APEX Tree in my application (Version 5.1 universal theme). It is on a global page and serves as a navigation region in my application. It is on most pages of my application. The problem is sometimes the tree gets really huge with around 5000 - 6000 records and It takes time to load on every page I navigate, hence delaying the response. It is bad for performance. 
I want to make the region static and don't want to load it on every page. 
So, the page loads but the tree should remain there.

Can we make a region on global page not load every time. Is there a way to restrict it?

Comment: You need to identify your performance bottleneck. If the delay is happening on server-side because for example the SQL Source of your tree takes time to process, then the answer from @hinotf and the `Server Cache` will help. If it instead takes time on client-side to parse the HTML code of the tree, then `Server Cache` won't help at all, since it still needs to be sent to and parsed by the browser on each page load. Consider cutting down your navigation tree or move it to a modal page a user can open whenever he needs to.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the suggestion. It is the parsing which takes time not the SQL, I have checked the sql performance.

Answer (score 2):

There is `Server Cache` region's property:

> Select how the Application Express engine can cache HTML text
> on the server side. If caching can be used, it emits the cached result
> instead of computing it again. This cuts down on expensive computation
> time on the server. This feature is unrelated to the browser's caching
> capabilities.
>
> Available options include:
>
> Disabled. Content is not cached and computed for each request.
>
> Enabled. Content is cached and utilized by all users.
>
> Cache By User. Content is > cached specifically for each user.
>
> Cache By Session. Content is cached specifically for each session.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the answer I will give it a try.